# angularJS parentNode of directive is null

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have defined a directive, and specified the template and added an compile function. just like below

```
mainApp.directive("mySpan", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span style=\"background-color:gray;color:orange\">pppdsf</span>',
        replace: true,
        require:'^uiScroll',
        compile: function (template, attrs) {
            return {
                post:function (scope, element, attrs, scrollController) {
                    var pp = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but there is an error can't find the scrollController. the reason is that the `template[0].parentNode.parentNode` is `null`, so it could not find the parentNode's controller property. Has anyone encountered this error before?

```
<div ng-controller="mainController as mainCtr">
    <ul class="dataArea">
        <li ui-scroll="item in suggestionList.dataSource" buffer-size="10">
            <my-span></my-span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share some of the HTML ?

Comment: I have add it, of course , the ui-scroll is a directive in github. it is used to implement the functionality as ng-repeat. but it will display data more quickly. at the compile phase i debug the ui-scroll, all the added  li element have parentNode, but when compile the myspan directive it lost parentNode and throw the error.

Comment: Try without the `replace` property (it's deprecated now anyway)

Comment: remove the replace property, it can't work also.